# IOS date to string gives me wrong date

Tags: ios, datetime, time

I am working with a time stamp that shows the following from my server:2015-07-23T17:08:00Z. However, I have tried multiple ways to extract the month and it keeps returning "January". When I turn the date stamp into a string, I get the following:2015-01-23 17:08:00 +0000. Does anyone know why my month keeps getting reverted to Jan? Year Day , time is all fine... Any help appreciated.

Comment: Show your code, including the date format you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
NSString *dateAsString = @"2015-07-23T17:08:00Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateAsString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

My guess is that you have the wrong symbol for month in your `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: "'Z'" in date format is evil, it will ignore time zone then and use local time zone for date, should use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" without quotes

Comment: Works I appreciate it.